# there isn't relation between Base Class library & Asp.net Runtime

Tags: asp.net, .net, base-class-library

I study [Overview of .net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in first part it said:

> The **class library** is a comprehensive, object-oriented collection of
>   reusable types that you can use to develop applications ranging from
>   traditional command-line or graphical user interface (GUI)
>   applications to applications based on the latest innovations provided
>   by **ASP.NET, such as Web Forms and XML Web services**

And next:

> ASP.NET hosts the runtime to provide a scalable, server-side
>   environment for managed code. ASP.NET works directly with the runtime
>   to enable ASP.NET applications and XML Web services, both of which are
>   discussed later in this topic

But there isn't any relation, any base class library layer between Asp.net and managed Code, in illustration. why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the ASP.NET runtime is [not written in managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx):

> The ASP.NET ISAPI extension is a Win32 DLL and does not host managed code. [...] The worker process is a small Win32 shell of code that hosts the common language runtime (CLR) and runs managed code.